# How to edit the position and scale of objects that have keyframes on those properties

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes

I have animated a sequence. It has keyframes on scale, rotation and location. So in order to composite the 3d animation, I will have to scale down the models and change their current positions.

Comment: you can delete the scale keyframes in the Dope Sheet, or parent the object to an empty and scale the empty

Comment: Or use an animation layer.

Comment: @L0Lock What do you mean by animation layer?

Comment: Push down the current animation as a new track in the NLA Editor, and animate a new position in a new track with its Blending mode set to Add. Similar to what I explained [there](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/305669/53447)

Answer (score 0):

I think one way should be to parent the object to an empty:

- to add an empty (shift + a)
- select an empty (a cube could be good for this operation)
- give the empty cube the same position the object has
- scale the empty to fit the object (Not important, but the right process)
- click the object first than the empty
- press ctrl + P and use 'object (keep Transform)' [should look like the image]
- now you can control the empty, scale it, move it, animate it and the object will follow
  [image]